# mysql query to update field to max(field) + 1

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1111

What I want to do is:

```
UPDATE table SET field = MAX(field) + 1 WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5, 6, 8);
```

The semantics of this statement, in my mind, would be first the database would go off and determine for me what the largest value of `field` is in all of `table`. It would then add 1 to that value, and assign the resulting value to the `field` column of the rows with `id` 1, 3, 5, 6, and 8. Seems simple enough...

When I try to run that query though, MySQL chokes on it and says:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

What's the secret sauce you have to use to get the outcome I desire?

Regards,
Vic

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE TABLE set field = ((SELECT selected_value FROM (SELECT MAX(field) AS selected_value FROM table) AS sub_selected_value) + 1) WHERE id in (1,3,5,6,8)
```

Comment: You did beat me, but you are missing a closing bracket :P

Answer (score 9):

In order to get around the `mysql-error-1093`, use a subquery/derived table/inline view:

```
UPDATE table
      SET field = (SELECT x.max_field
                          FROM (SELECT MAX(t.field) + 1 AS max_field
                                        FROM TABLE t
                                       WHERE t.id IN (1,3,5,6,8) ) x)
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket after `t.id IN (1,3,5,6,8) **)** x)`