# Mysql: Sub-query update on same table?

Tags: mysql

I can see why this is problematic, but can't seem to work out the fix like others here on SO have..

I wan't to incement the ticket number using a sub_query. Can't use auto_inc as already have an auto_inc'ing primary key..

Here's what i want to do:

```
UPDATE tickets SET tickets.ticket_number=(
    SELECT (MAX(ticket_number)+1) FROM tickets
) WHERE ticket_id=12345;
```

Gives me: `You can't specify target table 'tickets' for update in FROM clause`

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want to update one row, or *every* row?

Comment: The synchronicity man

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3332026

Comment: i deleted my answer, it will work but we need to know what you are trying to do... i think there's a better way...

Comment: Sorry, there's a WHERE on the end now...

Comment: Just like the error says - you cannot update a table from which you're reading.

Comment: I can see solutions for other people's similar questions however no one is giving a blueprint style answer, instead including the OP's huge queries so its hard to see what's actually fixed it!

Comment: Just curious:  why don't you make life easier and use the primary key for the ticket number?

Comment: i have a ticket_id for each ticket and then a "ticket_number" for each ticket at each event..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it a result you wanted to achieve?:

```
UPDATE tickets SET tickets.ticket_number=(
   SELECT max_ticket FROM (
   SELECT (MAX(ticket_number)+1) AS max_ticket FROM tickets ) AS sub_table) 
WHERE ticket_id=12345;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run across this before.  In mySQL, you have to create another layer of abstraction when trying to update a table with values from the same table.

```
UPDATE tickets SET ticket_number=(
  select t from (  
  SELECT (MAX(ticket_number)+1) t FROM tickets t1) as t2
) WHERE ticket_id=12345;
```

[Link to Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62467/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    update tickets
    set ticket_number= (
       select (MAX(ticket_number)+1) from (
          select * from ticket
       ) as x)
    where ticket_id=12345;
```