# Update query with max function with where clause

Tags: mysql, max, where-clause, clause

I have been trying to get through with the following query:

```
UPDATE transactions 
SET proposal= MAX(proposal) + 1 
WHERE id =1054
```

But it shows error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332026/mysql-query-to-update-field-to-maxfield-1

Comment: Try putting parens around your set block: `SET proposal = (MAX(proposal) + 1)

Comment: _"But it shows error"_ - what is the error? Can you post the exact error text?

Comment: thank you very much.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332026/mysql-query-to-update-field-to-maxfield-1 is the query I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a sub-query based on your criteria which is unclear at this point.  MAX() is typically based on an aggregate and not what you have.  Without knowing more, your query probably needs to be something like...

```
UPDATE transactions 
   SET proposal = 1 + ( select MAX(proposal) from transactions where SomeCondition )
   WHERE id = 1054
```

So the inner select MAX() is getting a proposal amount from the transaction table, but I don't know what your criteria is that you need.  If the transaction table has many records with id = 1054, then your inner "SomeCondition" would also be... "id = 1054".

if you are trying to compare to another transaction and want the highest, then adjust as needed.

Comment: I have tried with your query with insignificant modification.the result is as follows:
\ SQL query: Documentation


UPDATE transactions 
   SET proposal = 1 + ( select MAX(proposal) from transactions where SomeCondition )
   WHERE id = 1051
MySQL said: Documentation

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'transactions' for update in FROM clause